# JOIN no BigQuery

Tags: sql, bigquery

Preciso fazer a consulta a seguir, porém o BigQuery apresenta erro: *Name CNPJ_radical not found inside A at [3:6]*

Por que não consigo chamar o alias no ON do JOIN?

```
SELECT FORMAT(LPAD(A.CNPJ,8,'0')) as CNPJ_radical, A.DEBITO , A.CCF , A.PROTESTO , A.QTD, A.FLAG_RESTRICAO, B.porte  
FROM `analytics-eda-0186.qualidade_de_dados.FLAG_RESTRICAO_PJ_202010` as A
INNER JOIN `data-3660.dados_views.v_TB_DADOS_ABERTOS_CNPJ_MES10`as B
ON A.CNPJ_radical = substr(B.numero_de_inscricao , 1 , 8)
```

Comment: Porque o filtro ocorre antes do `SELECT`. Logo seu campo `CNPJ_rapical` só é computado após a busca dos dados filtrados pelo SGBD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Bigquery até onde eu sei não "entende" o alias. Então é só você repetir a função no ON assim:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(LPAD(A.CNPJ,8,'0')) as CNPJ_radical, 
    A.DEBITO , 
    A.CCF , 
    A.PROTESTO , 
    A.QTD, 
    A.FLAG_RESTRICAO, 
    B.porte  

FROM `analytics-eda-0186.qualidade_de_dados.FLAG_RESTRICAO_PJ_202010` as A
    INNER JOIN `data-3660.dados_views.v_TB_DADOS_ABERTOS_CNPJ_MES10`as B 
        ON FORMAT(LPAD(A.CNPJ,8,'0')) = substr(B.numero_de_inscricao , 1 , 8)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).